# AccessibilityService

Tags: android, android-manifest

i have created this code:
(AccActivity.java)

```
package bad.android.acc;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AccActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



    }

public void lunch(View v) {

    Log.d("TAS", "OnClick");

}

}
```

And (Access.java) - extends AccessibilityService

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;

public class Access extends AccessibilityService{

private static final long EVENT_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 50;


@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TAS", "onAccessibilityEvent");

}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TAS", "onInterrupt");
}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected (){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("TAS", "onServiceConnected");
    setServiceInfo();
}

 private void setServiceInfo() {
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        // We are interested in all types of accessibility events.
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
        // We want to provide specific type of feedback.
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
        // We want to receive events in a certain interval.
        info.notificationTimeout = EVENT_NOTIFICATION_TIMEOUT_MILLIS;
        // We want to receive accessibility events only from certain packages.
        info.packageNames = new String[1];
        // only handle this package
        info.packageNames[0] = getPackageName();  
        setServiceInfo(info);

  }
}
```

and Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="bad.android.acc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AccActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 <service android:name=".Access">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Now, how do I start the service accessibilty "Access.java"? as a normal service? I am a little confused with this service ..
thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Accessibility" is hidden on MIUI, you should press "Search" button and enter "Accessibility" (Maybe in Chinese  "辅助功能" ), and then you can turn on it.

Answer (score 0):

This could help you :

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccessibilityService/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I understood and I have resolved. I could not figure out how to turn on the service as MIUI, because the menu "Accessibility" has been hidden.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, it seems you want to open the Accessibility Settings.

If so, the following code launches the Accessibility Settings:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```